# How to do a server-side pagination with Kendo in Angular 4

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to achive server side pagination in the kendo ui for angular 2,4,6  library and i cant find a way to do it. 
It seems its only work with client side pagination.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link for detailed explanation

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/server-side-paging-in-kendo-grid-for-angular-2/